# C++, Searching and returning value

Tags: c++

For example, lets say I have this string:

```
"Name, Name2, <b>Name3</b>, Name4, <b>Name5</b>"
```

I am trying to get whatever value / name is inside the `<b>` tags. So when I search the char, I get the following in an array:

```
Name3
Name5
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You can have a look at `string::find` : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/.

Answer (score 4):

For this type of string searching / matching approach, just use [boost regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic version using only STL which assumes that the tags are not nested or otherwise misbehaving

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const std::string TAG_OPEN( "<b>" );
    const std::string TAG_CLOSE( "</b>" );
    const std::string s( "Name, Name2, <b>Name3</b>, Name4, <b>Name5</b>" );

    typedef std::vector< std::string > StringArray;
    StringArray tagContents;

    std::string::size_type index = 0;
    while( index != std::string::npos )
    {
        const std::string::size_type o = s.find( TAG_OPEN, index );
        if ( o == std::string::npos )
        {
            break;
        }

        const std::string::size_type c = s.find( TAG_CLOSE, index );
        if ( c == std::string::npos )
        {
            // mismatched tag, ignore?
            break;
        }

        const std::string::size_type tagContentsStart  = o + TAG_OPEN.size();
        const std::string::size_type tagContentsFinish = c;
        tagContents.push_back(
            s.substr( tagContentsStart
                    , tagContentsFinish - tagContentsStart ) );

        index = c + TAG_CLOSE.size();
    }


    for ( StringArray::const_iterator S  = tagContents.begin();
                                      S != tagContents.end();
                                    ++S )
    {
        std::cout << *S << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @pure841: Well yes but most, if not all, C++ algorithms will work with some sort of wrapper around raw chars such as `std::string`. If you really only want to work with chars you should probably re-tag the question as C rather than C++.

Comment: @pure841:  Put your chars into a `std::string`, then use the `std::string` for parsing.

Comment: So, you saying its easier to convert the char to string, and then parse it?

Answer (score 0):

```
start = strstr(s, "<b>")+3;
stop = strstr(start, "</b>");
strncpy(result, start, stop-start);
```

Don't forget to add error checking.

subsequent matches, for the lazy ones:

```
s = stop+3;
```

execute the above code again.

[EDIT] To stop/error checking: check return code of strstr.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is tagged C++, not C. Also this only returns one match.

Comment: This only works for one match. What if there were multiple matches?

Comment: strstr and strncpy are also available in C++. :)

Comment: How do I stop it once it doesnt find any more matches?

Comment: Downvoted. This is C++, not C, and use of those functions should be absolutely discouraged.

Comment: @deadmg, do it with fewer lines in C++, then discourage.

Comment: There's nothing inherently bad about using these functions, but the way strncpy is used here invites buffer overrun.

Comment: I agree that you should prefer STL APIs when possible. For instance, fstream is RAII unlike fopen(). I agree that std::string is better than char* in 99% of the cases. But one shouldn't get carried away, and nobody remembers STL syntax anyway.

Comment: Wow, Neil, you just have it in for me. In what circumstances should a C++ developer use buggy, insecure C APIs instead of the more secure and greater functionality offered by STL?

Answer (score 0):

If you refuse to use `std::string` and insist on using C-style string, you can always be adventurous and use `strtok`.  It has the feature of modifying your text strings.

Please read up on the side-effects of `strtok` before using it.

I still strongly suggest making a `std::string` with your chars, then using the `std::string` for parsing.  There are a lot more features with `std::string` than with C-style strings.